# How to read file to the list of lists in R?

Tags: r

Do you have any idea how to read that kind of data from txt file?

```
<5, <4, 3>>
<5, <6, 7>>
<1, <1, 2>>
<3, <1, 10>>
<2, <8, 8>>
```

The expected result is a list of lists where the rows look like:

```
list(
    list(5, c(4, 3))
    list(5, c(6, 7))
    list(1, c(1, 2))
    list(3, c(1, 10))
    list(2, c(1, 8))
    )
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the help of `jsonlite::fromJSON`:

```
dat <- readLines("data.txt")
# replace '<' with '[' and '>' with ']'
dat <- gsub(">", "]", gsub("<", "[", dat))
# collapse with comma separation
dat <- paste0(dat, collapse = ",")
# encapsulates between '[' and ']'
dat <- sprintf("[%s]", dat)
# convert to R object
jsonlite::fromJSON(dat)
```

The result:

```
> str(jsonlite::fromJSON(dat))
List of 5
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int 5
  ..$ : int [1:2] 4 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int 5
  ..$ : int [1:2] 6 7
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int 1
  ..$ : int [1:2] 1 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int 3
  ..$ : int [1:2] 1 10
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int 2
  ..$ : int [1:2] 8 8
```